# Prevent the updated_at field in User to get modified while signing in using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-activerecord

I have a situation where I need to use the `updated_at` field of all the models to create a synchronize functionality. But In case of User model, the `updated_at` field gets modified every time a user signs in. Even worse is the case, when a device signs in with a user's credentials to sync data `updated_at` field just gets modified before sync has even started.

So, My question is, Is there a way we can stop devise to update the `updated_at` field when a user signs in?

Comment: do you happend to figure out a solution for this ? it's killing my cache strategies ;(

Comment: @fixusaas No.. I had to change my sync logic.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I did: override the should_record_timestamps? method on the devise model to not change the updated_at column when only the Devise fields are updated.
Here's the code, it handles Devise::Trackable and Rememberable.

```
  def should_record_timestamps?
    (self.changes.keys.map(&:to_sym) - (Devise::Models::Trackable.required_fields(nil) + [:remember_token, :remember_created_at])).present? && super
  end
```

This is a great way of not invalidating the caches when a user logs in.

Answer (score 2):

Devise has changed, so this question warrants an updated answer.

In my user model, I overrode the `updated_tracked_fields!`. This has been in since [May 21, 2014 (v. 3.3.0)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/451be888cb7c2e2e63222f012308f5304236a704).

```
def update_tracked_fields!(request)
  update_tracked_fields(request)
  update_attrs = changes.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), object|
    object[key] = value[1]
  end
  update(update_attrs)
end
```

The `update` method is used instead of `save` because it automatically skips validations and updating the `updated_at` column, and I reworked the `update_attrs` because `update` requires a hash for all the columns that need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another column to the model and update the datetime on that instead of trying to change how `updated_at` works.

Otherwise you would need to change Devise to do something like:

```
User.record_timestamps = false
# devise save/update action
User.record_timestamps = true
```

Comment: I have already tried the second method but it is devise what changing the updated_at. I am not able to locate what controller or method to override to add this.